# Fetching data from JSON file returning nothing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, react-hooks

I am building a solar system app and I want to have all of my planet's info in a JSON file for easy access. The JSON file is in the following format

Planet-info.json, in the `public` folder of my React app

```
  "planets": [
        {
            "Name": "Mercury",
            "Description": "The smallest planet in our solar system and closest to the Sun—is only slightly larger than Earth's Moon. Mercury is the fastest planet, zipping around the Sun every 88 Earth days.",
            "Moons": 0,
            "Habititable": "false"
        },
        {
            "Name": "Venus",
            "Description": "is hot",
            "Moons": 0,
            "Habititable": "false"
        }
    ]
```

And I am fetching the data with the `useEffect` hook

```
 const [planetData, setPlanetData] = useState();
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = () => {
      fetch("/planet-info.json").then((result) => {
        setPlanetData(result);
      });
    };
    fetchData();
    console.log(`planet data is ${planetData}`);
  }, []);
```

However when this code runs and the console.log statement runs it returns the line
`planet data is` 
It does not say `undefined`, or even `[Object object]` it is simply blank and I am unable to troubleshoot from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fetchData` runs asynchronously. So what's happening is

1. `fetchData` starts
2. `console.log` executes(before the json file has the chance to load)
3. when the `fetch` completes, `setPlanetData(result)` happens.
   If you want to see the value printed out, this should do it:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  fetch("/planet-info.json").then(result => {
    const json = result.json();
    console.log(json);
    setPlanetData(json);
  });
});
```

Comment: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined` I think I am running the function in the wrong place.

Comment: Oops missed a line in my answer. I fixed it now. Needs a `return` in `fetchData`

Comment: It is no longer crashing, but now it is logging `undefined`

Comment: Lol look at me making mistakes. Fixed it now.

Comment: I made another update. Your JSON is probably fine. It's how `fetch` gets it back. You can use the `json` function on the response object to get the JSON value.